# History of EAFNOSUPPORT semantics?

Tags: sockets, posix, errno

I’m seeing three different “error strings” for the `EAFNOSUPPORT` / `WSAEAFNOSUPPORT` errno:

- POSIX:

  > The implementation does not support the specified address family.
- BSD (`errno.h`, `_sys_errlist[]`):

  > Address family not supported by protocol family
- Windows®/Winsock2:

  > An address incompatible with the requested protocol was used

While the semantics of the latter two are pretty much identical, the former differs quite a bit (it does not reference a protocol family; rather, it states that the given address family is not supported in a particular place).

I’m assuming both interpretations are valid, especially given `EPFNOSUPPORT` (“Protocol family not supported”) is marked as nōn-POSIX in the BSD headers, but where does this difference come from? Incidentally, my back-of-the-head/historical(FSVO) understanding of this errno code matches the POSIX semantics more than the BSD/Winsock semantics…

I can imagine that the POSIX semantic is from older BSD sockets, and later `EPFNOSUPPORT` was added so `EAFNOSUPPORT` was redesignated in BSD sockets (and Winsock just took that), or POSIX is deliberately written in a different way.

Can anyone shed light on this, perhaps explain the histories (code heritage, etc)?